# Z test (hypothesis proportion) revealing odd results

Tags: statistics

We are told the sample mean in a survey found that the proportion of people taking the bus was $0.554$ (sample mean) out of a total of $57$ students in the survey. The alternative hypothesis claims that less than half of the class travels by bus. So presumably the null would be more than half or equal to half took the bus. So $n = 57 $ and the number of people taking bus is $31$ so sample mean is $0.554$ and the proportion we are hypothesising is $0.5$?

$H_{alternative} : < 0.5$

$H_{null}:   P \geq 0.5$

So I started to work out the $Z$ statistic to find the $p$-value, using this formula

$T = \frac{p-P }{ \sqrt{(P(1-P)}{n}}$
so
$T = \frac{0.554 - 0.5 }{ \sqrt\frac{(0.5(1-0.5)}{56}}$

$T = 0.81$

which would give me a $p$-value of $0.7910$. Which I thought was very high for just a one sample and one tailed test. Am I doing something wrong here? Or does it just mean that there's no way I can reject the null hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand with this type of hypothesis testing is that you are using the Normal distribution to approximate the Binomial distribution. Now, with that out of the way, you have $n=57$ and $\hat p=0.554$, where $\hat p$ is the estimated proportion of students who travelled by bus **based on your survey**.

Given that your $H_0: p=0.5$ and $H_A: p>0.5$, you calculate your $Z$-value. Your first "minor" mistake is the usage of the test statistic. You should simply say $$Z=\frac{\hat p -p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}n}}$$ instead of using the $T$ test statistic because you are actually referring to two different distributions.

With that out of the way, you calculated a value of $$Z=\frac{0.554-0.5}{\sqrt{\frac{0.5\cdot0.5}{57}}}=0.815$$
because $n=57$, not $56$. Remember you are using the normal to approximate the binomial, hence the $T$-statistic is inappropriate here.

With that, the $p$-value $0.791$. It might sound very high, but you are looking at the *wrong* side of the curve. Look at the alternative hypothesis $-$ it is a *right-tailed* test, so you reject the null if the $p$-value is greater than some critical $p$-value, usually $0.01,\,0.05$ or $0.10$. In your case, the $p$-value you should have received is $1-0.791=0.209$. Hence, you actually *cannot* reject the null hypothesis! This value means that if you constantly draw a sample from your population, you would realize that the proportion from your sample (who travel by bus) is significantly not different from your hypothesized value.

As extended exercises, consider what would happen if you:

1. change the value of $p$ in your hypotheses
2. continuously sample from your population (you could use Excel to do it!), with *different* simulated proportions

Comment: Woops sorry about using 'T', I've been doing t tests for the past couple hours - wasn't intended^^ But awesome answer thank you. One thing I just want to clarify, when you say its a right tailed test, and that you do 1-0.791, isn't my test a lower tailed rather than upper tailed? since I am looking at values lower than not greater than. If this isn't lower would this work the same way if I was looking at lower tail? Thanks

Comment: For that, you should look at what $0.791$ means. It actually is the area under the normal curve to the left of the $z$-value. Since your test is towards the right, you should look at the area to the right of the $z$-value. If you were to look at the lower tail, you can apply accordingly. If you perform a two-tail test, then it is once again different.